# Assign resolved promise to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a factory which returns token as

```
var accessToken = Restangular.all(url);
            accessToken.one('token').get()
              .then(function(res) {
                deferred.resolve(res.data);
              })
              .catch(function(errRes) {
                deferred.reject(errRes);
              });
            return deferred.promise;
```

In my header Interceptor, I need to get the token. Tried below code :

```
  var accessToken;

              $injector.get('tokenService').accessToken().then(function(res) {
                accessToken = res.access_token;
              }, function(e) {
                // error
              });

             req.headers = _.extend({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
              }, req.headers);
```

Every time I get accessToken as `undefined`. There should be an easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are forming `req.headers` outside `accessToken()`'s ajax call. Which tend to make your `res.headers` object with undefined `access_token`. Ideally you should wait until `accessToken()` ajax gets complete & set your `res.headers` code inside `accessToken().then`.

**Factory**

```
var accessToken = Restangular.all(url);
    return accessToken.one('token').get()
       .then(function(res) {
           return res.data;
       })
       .catch(function(errRes) {
          return errRes;
       });
}
```

**Interceptor**

```
var accessToken;
$injector.get('tokenService').accessToken().then(function(res) {
     accessToken = res.access_token;
     req.headers = _.extend({
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
     }, req.headers);
}, function(e) {
     // error
});
```